# Force an integer to be two digits - VB

Tags: vb.net, integer

I have a variable that holds a string `"02100030000000000000000000D5010008D501000804"` and I'm byte separating the string using

```
For i As Integer = 1 To (stringReader.Length - 1) Step 2
                'Get the successive 2-character substrings, parse as bytes and add to total
                Dim b As Byte = Byte.Parse(stringReader.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
                sum = sum + CInt(b)

            Next
```

I'm converting the strings to direct integers.e.g:(string"10" to Integer10 and ).  That works fine.  But Whenever I convert the string"02" to Integer, I get only Integer(2) and I need Integer(02).  How can I proceed with?

My code is:

```
stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()      
byt = stringReader(1) + stringReader(2)
```

stringreader contains something like `"100030000000000000000000D5010008D501000804"`

Byte separation

```
For i As Integer = 1 To (stringReader.Length - 1) Step 2
                'Get the successive 2-character substrings, parse as bytes and add to total
                Dim b As Byte = Byte.Parse(stringReader.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
                sum = sum + CInt(b)

            Next
```

Comment: When storing integers there is no difference between 2 and 02.

Comment: You may try this:- x.ToString("D2")

Comment: What if it was 3 digits? Do you want to throw validation exception? Also, what about negative values? Do you expect "-00" to be a valid value?

Comment: @RobP. Yes, But I want it as a byte as this is used as the address of a particular location.

Comment: @Neolisk I use to have only two digits as standard and also I don use three digits as I do byte separation.

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimhanRavichandra I think that the value needing to be a byte is a significant enough change to have it added to the question...

Comment: How do you do byte separation? Please add an example to your question. You don't have to have it as a string to do byte separation, you should work directly with integer.

Comment: Honestly, I think this question could benefit from a lot more context - in particular some actual code...

Comment: @Psychemaster I have added a code piece

Comment: You loop starts at 1, you're missing the first character. I find it weird that you are adding to sum in that way. Integer 02 does not exists, the string "02" does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
number.ToString("D2")
```

where `number` is an integral type like `System.Int32`(`Integer`).

Further reading: [Standard Numeric Format Strings: The Decimal ("D") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#DFormatString)

If you have a `String` instead you could also use `String.PadLeft`:

```
"2".PadLeft(2, "0"c)  ' -> "02"
```

Comment: Is the same possible with integers?

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimhanRavichandra: of course, integer is the same as `Int32`.

Comment: I mean to ask, is it possible to Pad an integer, left with zero?

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimhanRavichandra: but `ToString("D2")` does exactly this and it does not need a `String` so it fits perfectly. Haven't you tested it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hazarding a guess, he's not looking for a solution that changes what is displayed, rather what is stored. Note this simply cannot be done with the built in Integer datatype...